# Pasting data from multiple dictionary into a csv // with python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary

Since this morning I have been struggling with the below code. I'm still new to python. I hope to be able to join you guys in helping people, but for now, I'm the newbie.

I created a class product with a static variable to store all of them.

```
class Product(dict):
all_p=[]

def __init__(self):
    self['Nom'] = ','
    self['Marque'] = ','
    self['Description'] = ','
    self['Formule'] = ','

    all_p.append(self)
```

From the loop I'm generating my product list, I eventually get:

```
for i in range(0, len(all_p)):
    print(all_p[i])
```

all my products.
(there might be a better way to do it, but as this works, I'm okay with it).

Here is an example of my product list:

```
[{'Nom': 'Mustard', 'Marque':'Heinz','Description','enjoy the meal!',
'Formule':['ingredient0','ingredient1','ingredient2','ingredient3','ingredient4']},
{'Nom': 'Ketchup', 'Marque':'Amora','Description','best with mussels',
'Formule':['ing0','ingredient1','ing2','ingredient3','ingredient4']}]
```

HERE IS MY REAL QUESTION:

I would like to add this information into a csv file called `myfile.csv` located in `C:\Users\myfolder` in this format :

```
Col1            Col2                Col3                    ...
Nom             Mustard             Ketchup                 ...
Marque          Heinz               Amora                   ...
Description     enjoy the meal!     best with mussels       ...
formule         ['ingredient0',...] ['ing0',...]            ...
```

Sorry if I'm too specific. Shouldn't be too complicated but I have errors when parsing `all_p[i]` and adding the info into my Excel.
Your help would be awesome !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below code.

> Please take care while specifying the field width. Here have statically taken as **75** as your lists are of huge length.

```
details =[{'Nom': 'Mustard', 'Marque':'Heinz','Description': 'enjoy the meal!','Formule':['ingredient0','ingredient1','ingredient2','ingredient3','ingredient4']},{'Nom': 'Ketchup', 'Marque':'Amora','Description': 'best with mussels','Formule':['ing0','ingredient1','ing2','ingredient3','ingredient4']}]

# print (details)

d = {}
for detail in details:
    for k, v in detail.items():
        if k in d:
            d[k].append(v)
        else:
            d[k] = [v]

# print (d)
# print(tuple("Col" + str(i) for i in range(1, len(d["Nom"])+2)) )
if d:
    format_str =  "%-75s\t"*(len(d["Nom"])+1) 
    # print (format_str)
    s = format_str %tuple("Col" + str(i) for i in range(1, len(d["Nom"])+2)) + "\n"

for k, v in d.items():
    s += format_str % (k, *v) + "\n"

print (s)
```

#### Output»

```
Col1                                                                        Col2                                                                        Col3                                                                        
Nom                                                                         Mustard                                                                     Ketchup                                                                     
Description                                                                 enjoy the meal!                                                             best with mussels                                                           
Formule                                                                     ['ingredient0', 'ingredient1', 'ingredient2', 'ingredient3', 'ingredient4'] ['ing0', 'ingredient1', 'ing2', 'ingredient3', 'ingredient4']               
Marque                                                                      Heinz                                                                       Amora
```

And finally, you can write this string to file using the below code.

```
with open("C:\\Users\\myfolder\\myfile.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(s)
```

Comment: hi @hygull, and thanks a lot. i get a "unexpected EOF while parsing" with the open statement at the end of your answer. Is this due to my User name being "Rémy" with an accent ?

Comment: Yes @Madmaxoo, please use `with open("C:\\Users\\myfolder\\myfile.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8")` and please comment your queries if it solves your problem or you face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

First convert your list of dictionaries to a pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(all_p)
```

Then you can reshape the data how you want it using pandas, and finally use the pandas function `to_csv()` to write the DataFrame to a CSV file.

The documentation for `to_csv()` is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Comment: sorry Alex, but your comment doesn't help me out.. Can someone please help ??